# copy jars used by plugin to single folder using Maven

Tags: maven

In my POM.xml other the plugin configuration, i am not required to configure any dependenices to run the plugin. I would like to download dependent jars used by plugin(soapui-maven-plugin) from the repository into one single folder. I  tried the command "mvn dependency:copy-dependencies", but no jars are copied. Is there any way to do it?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>service.report</groupId>
<artifactId>service-report</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Maven 2 SoapUI Sample</name>  
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>           
        <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
        <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>            
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>loadtest</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>                             
                            <projectFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xxxxx-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                            <testSuite>xxxx</testSuite>
                            <testCase>sssss</testCase>
                            <loadTest>LoadTest 1</loadTest>
                            <outputFolder>${basedir}/target/surefire</outputFolder>
                            <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                            <exportAll>true</exportAll>
                            <printReport>true</printReport>
                            <testFailIgnore>false</testFailIgnore>
                            <!-- <projectProperties>
                                <value>message=Hello World!</value>
                            </projectProperties> -->
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Why do you want to copy them? what is your goal?

Answer (score 1):

mvn dependency:copy-dependencies is only applied to current maven module only. It won't works on plugins. If you want to download all soapui-maven-plugin dependencies, you need to execute command from soapui-maven-plugin project. You can follow the following steps. I assumed you familiar with GIT CLI. If not, you need to manually download from https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui

```
git clone https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui
cd soapui/soapui-maven-plugin
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

You can get list of dependencies in soapui/soapui-maven-plugin/target/dependency (total 82files)

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project soapui-maven-plugin: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:5.0.0: Could not find artifact javafx:jfxrt:jar:2.2 at specified path (your jdk path)
```

If you get the above error, it means your maven jdk is version jdk.1.7 (u6 or earlier) which is not installed with javafx. Download newer jdk that comes with javafx at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html . Remember change your maven jdk to this newer jdk.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the dependency-plugin you could add the dependencies to the pom...and download with the depepndency-plugin...

It works right for me...

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.ab.forge.utility.copydependenciespom</groupId>
<artifactId>copydependenciespom</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<!-- BINARIES -->
<dependencies>
    <!--CUSTOMER RETURN -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ab...</groupId>
        <artifactId>customerret.....</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>

                        <excludeGroupIds>com.ab.ah.scad.acl</excludeGroupIds>
                        <excludeTypes>pom</excludeTypes>
                        <includeGroupIds>com.ab.oneleo</includeGroupIds>
                        <outputDirectory>${outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

After I just run the install passing the -DoutputDirectory parameter....

Try this...

To view all the plugin dependencies you can run a dependency:tree on the pom (where the plugin in configured)